# How can I know android game is developed with Unity game engine?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering

I have an android apk which I have decompiled. All libraries used are known to me. This include image loading and cachine libraries, airbnb lootie and crashlytics among others. I am trying to figure out the game engine used for the android apk. I have come across com.unity3d.ads which am not sure confirms this was developed on Unity3D. Can I use this to confirm? How can I know if this was done on android or if a game engine was used?

Comment: Change `.apk` to `.zip` and open that , If you found `assets/bin/data/Resources/unity_builtin_extra` in there , I think it's build from unity.

Comment: @TimChang /bin folder doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

You cannot infer through com.unity3d.ads that the app is developed with Unity. You can use Unity Ads SDK to add advertisement to any platform iOS, Android or Java.

Extract the apk and navigate to lib folder and search libunity.so or libmono.so. If any of the file exists means the App was developed with Unity otherwise it is not.